# Post an XML request to the URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have an API URL where I want to post the XML data. My API URL only accept XML. I am posting my XML to URL using `ajax`.
Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <lead>
    <key>*****</key>
    <id>*****</id>  
    <data6>Lead has been updated. merchant</data6>
  </lead>
</data>
```

and my `JavaScript` code is:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Add Quote</button>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var data = "<data><lead><key>*****</key><id><?php echo $id; ?></id><data6>Lead has been updated. merchant</data6></lead></data>";
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                            url: "https://inspire.flg360.co.uk/api/APILeadCreateUpdate.php",
                            data: data,
                            contentType: "text/xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            cache: false,
                            error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
                            success: function(xml) {
                                alert("it works");
                                alert($(xml).find("project")[0].attr("id"));
                            }
            });

    }
    </script>
```

When I click the add quote button then it goes into error block of the ajax function. I have given the data posting URL and XML data in the code.

Comment: You've just posted your API key and URL to the Internet. You'll want to revoke and/or change the key immediately.

Comment: Check your browser network tab and see if you are getting any stacktrace from the server in the response and also the HTTP error code. On the other hand, don't forget to include the parameters in your error function (if that helps in something). Being honest, with the vague details that you gave it's almost impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @OscarJara Here is the live code http://www.companycompare.co.uk/success.php?id=119450656

Comment: <facepalm> Egad man. It's needed to post *to the API*, it's not needed to post here. You've essentially just given us all your password. Anybody anywhere on the Internet can now make changes to your account by using the key you posted.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Oh! Thanks, mate.

Comment: This is my new favorite post.

Comment: You need to change your key. Right away. The post's history will have the key. Change it now! :)

Comment: Also, can you add what is the actual error you're getting? It may be being passed as an argument to your "error" function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this snippet inside a wordpress template.

The first thing is, you should enclose all your codes with [jQuery No Conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

The reason why it does not do anything is `$` is not being recognized. So, replace `$` by `jQuery` and then your code will work properly.

Make sure you have declared the `$id` variable inside a `PHP` block right before the script.

I have ran it [here](http://atiqur.com/testing/)

Hope it works!